# How to fetch value of captcha image using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, decode, captcha

Is there a way that I can get the captcha image value using jquery/javascript and put it on the validation box?

Something I want to do on a form like below:

[image]

And the code for captcha is written like below:

```
<td><img id="form_rcdl:j_idt33:j_idt38" src="/rcdlstatus/DispplayCaptcha?txtp_cd=1&amp;bkgp_cd=2&amp;noise_cd=2&amp;gimp_cd=3&amp;txtp_length=5&amp;pfdrid_c=true?1388469581&amp;pfdrid_c=true" alt=""></td>
```

Comment: If you could do that, then why would captcha ever be used?

Comment: There is no point in reading captcha at client side and validate it. What exactly you want to achieve here?

Comment: Yes. That's true. But I am just curious if we can do that.

Comment: I want to automate it in a simple page.

Answer (score 4):

Usually, these kinds of captcha are easy to pass/hack.

Now, this is can be done in different ways using other programming languages.
But as you are looking for a client side solution [`tesseract.js`](http://tesseract.projectnaptha.com/) might help.

I have not tried that before, but using it seems straightforward

```
Tesseract.recognize(myImage)
       .progress(function  (p) { console.log('progress', p)    })
       .then(function (result) { console.log('result', result) })
```

Here is a demo [(On JSFiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/fxoy3Lc5/4/) you can try it `(Won't work on StackOverflow )`
you should get an alert says `road`

```js
let progress = document.querySelector('#progress');

Tesseract.recognize('https://image.ibb.co/bXhgST/captcha_5.jpg')
  .progress(function(p) {

    progress.innerHTML += JSON.stringify(p) + "<br>"
  })
  .then(function(result) {
    alert(result.text)
  })
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.rawgit.com/naptha/tesseract.js/1.0.10/dist/tesseract.js'></script>
<img id="img" src="https://image.ibb.co/bXhgST/captcha_5.jpg" />
<div id="progress"></div>
```

Another option would be using a professional service like [`Amazon Detecting Text in an Image`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/text-detection.html)

Comment: Let me try and will let u know the result.